# Java unclear ZipException for commons-codec

Tags: java, exception, logging

Everytime that I deploy my .war file in GlassFish 4.1, I get the following log.

Does it make any sense? Could the commons-codec-1.4.jar have any errors? 
I also tried with version 1.10, but I got the same errors...

This is a sample of the beggining of errors in the log:

```
[2015-07-28T01:55:03.215-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1438059303215] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting org/apache/commons/codec/BinaryDecoder.class of size 268
java.util.zip.ZipException: too many length or distance symbols
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:358)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2015-07-28T01:55:03.217-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1438059303217] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting org/apache/commons/codec/BinaryEncoder.class of size 268
java.util.zip.ZipException: too many length or distance symbols
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:358)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2015-07-28T01:55:03.218-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1438059303218] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting org/apache/commons/codec/Decoder.class of size 248
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:358)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2015-07-28T01:55:03.219-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1438059303219] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException.class of size 391
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:358)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2015-07-28T01:55:03.220-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1438059303220] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting org/apache/commons/codec/Encoder.class of size 248
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:358)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2015-07-28T01:55:03.221-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1438059303221] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting org/apache/commons/codec/EncoderException.class of size 391
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:358)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```